# how to achieve conditional app_offline.htm in asp .net IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I am going to upload new look of my site.my site is in ASP .NET , C#.

What i want that during my testing time the site should in Maintenance mode but i should be able to access the site.

So my question is can i have conditional app_offline.htm , so my site will be accessible from my IP and others will see app_offline page.

**Please note** I can change my IIS setting if required.

Comment: You could block all IPs but yours, but I don't think that will display a nice message to them.

Comment: i know that can be done but i think all other user will see "The Page cannot be reached" which is not good .. i want to show them site is under maintenance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly I dont think that is possible. App_offline.htm is a one-trick-pony and just takes the app offline.

You mention being able to amend IIS settings. Are you able to set up a second site within IIS and restrict access by IP address, therefore still having your existing site online.

Comment: we already have a second site running ans we did finished testing on that .. but there are some pages which require to have correct URL(as they are checking refrer) i want to test on actual URL in stead of second site URL(which is newtest.xyz.xom instead of www.xyz.com)

Comment: @Dhaval You may just have to stay up late one night (check your user activity) and take the site down at a time when the least amount of users are affected.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely this is the last option i have .. i will test site 1 in the night so i think least amount of users will get affect .. but i just want to check if any trick exists

Comment: i am accepting your answer as i did not have any other choice